# Why am I unable to import a local project module into a unit test module (Python3.9)?

Tags: python-import, python-unittest

I have a unit test project in Python 3.9 which is contained within a Visual Studio 2019CE project. This project needs to target Azure Data Factory. To talk to Azure Data Factory there is supporting modules/classes that need to be imported into the unit test module. When importing the supporting objects into a unit test module, the unit test module is no longer discoverable by test explorer.

**Import command:**

```
from tools.adf_client import ADFClient
```

**What can I import:**

```
import pyodbc
```

**What is the difference?**

`pyodbc` is installed and `tools.adf_client` is not, it is a file in the unit test project.

**What I have tried:**

I tried putting an empty module in the same directory as the unit test module and importing that into the unit test module. The unit test module is still not discoverable.

I have seen examples of people modifying the path. Other people have commented that this is not good practice.

**Possible solution:**

Creating a `setup.py` and installing supporting packages into the environment prior to unit-test project execution. This assumes that the problem is that the module is not installed.

Comment: What I did to resolve this was add a setup.py and installed the package.